# Convert if else to try catch

Tags: php, mysql, try-catch, if-statement

Can somebody help me in converting the following code written using if-else to try/catch. Also let me know is trycatch needed in this case or if-else is apt

```
$results = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($results)!=0)
{
    while(($result = mysql_fetch_row($results))!=FALSE)
    {
        $res   ="DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id ='".$result['id']."'";
        if(mysql_query($res)==false)
        {
            echo mysql_error();
            exit;
        }
    }
    echo $res   ="DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id ='".$id."'";
    if(mysql_query($res)!==false)
    {
        header("Location:list.php?m=4");
    }
    else
    {
        echo mysql_error();
        exit;
    }
}
else
{
    echo "Error";
}
```

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_exception.asp

Comment: Have you attempted yet? What part don't you understand? And yes, error handling is an appropriate usage of Exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the sound of it, it seems you think try/catch and if-else as the same behaviour. That is not the case. Try catch is used to prevent an exception from making the application crash or to handle exceptions gracefully, and to perform logging and giving user feedback. If-else (else if) is used to check the internal state of your application, and perform different actions accordingly.

Generally, a try-catch is less efficient than if there is a switch-case or else-if approach to the problem.

Answer (score 6):

`try...catch` only makes any sense if your functions are throwing exceptions. If they don't, there's nothing to `catch`. I'd start with this as a refactoring:

```
$results = mysql_query($query);
if (!mysql_num_rows($results)) {
    echo 'No results!';
    exit;
}

$ids = array();
while (($result = mysql_fetch_row($results)) !== false) {
    $ids[] = $result['id'];
}

$ids = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $ids);
$query = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN ('" . join("','", $ids) . "')";
if (!mysql_query($query)) {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}

$query = "DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id = '$id'";
if (!mysql_query($query)) {
    echo mysql_error();
    exit;
}

header("Location: list.php?m=4");
exit;
```

This can still be improved a lot, but it's already an improvement over your spaghetti logic. If you're seriously interested in properly using exceptions, you should first move on to properly using functions for repetitive tasks (like the `error, exit` parts), then possibly restructure the whole thing into classes and objects, and lastly use exceptions to communicate between the now nested layers. Maybe start using a PHP framework to get a feeling for the whole thing.

Putting exceptions into the above code would be hardly more than a `goto`, but **just for illustrative purposes**:

```
try {

    $results = mysql_query($query);
    if (!mysql_num_rows($results)) {
        throw new Exception('No results!');
    }

    $ids = array();
    while (($result = mysql_fetch_row($results)) !== false) {
        $ids[] = $result['id'];
    }

    $ids = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $ids);
    $query = "DELETE FROM table1 WHERE id IN ('" . join("','", $ids) . "')";
    if (!mysql_query($query)) {
        throw new Exception(mysql_error());
    }

    $query = "DELETE FROM table2 WHERE id = '$id'";
    if (!mysql_query($query)) {
        throw new Exception(mysql_error());
    }

    header("Location: list.php?m=4");
    exit;

} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;

}
```

Comment: Thanks deceze can u explain the catch part try {

   .......
} catch (Exception $e) {

    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    exit;

}

Comment: @Web You should read tutorials about exceptions, but in a nutshell: If any exception is thrown inside the `try` block, any following code in the block will be skipped and the `catch` block will be executed. The thrown exception will be passed to the `catch` block as `$e`. `$e` is an object with the method `getMessage`, which returns the message that was passed to it when it was created. I.e. the message will be "No results!" for the `throw new Exception('No results!')` exception.